# getting error segmentation fault (core dumped) process returned 139 (0x8B)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a list of pointer of the same class inside my class. but when I want to access the data, I get error.what should I do to resolve my problem. I am newbie to c++ and I can not figure it out the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class Alpha
{
    public:

    Alpha() {}

    Alpha(int val) : i(val) {}

    virtual ~Alpha() {}

    void addTarget(Alpha* alpha)
    {
        targets.push_back(alpha);
    }

    void display() {
        cout << i << " -------------";
    }

    private:
    int i; //!< Member variable "i"
    list<Alpha*> targets;

  };
```

and here is my main function:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <list>
  #include "Alpha.h"
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    list<Alpha> teamA, teamB;

    Alpha* alptr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
    alptr = new Alpha;
    teamA.push_back(*alptr);
    alptr = nullptr;
    }

   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
    alptr = new Alpha;
    teamB.push_back(*alptr);
    alptr = nullptr;
   }

   list<Alpha>::iterator it = teamA.begin();

   for(;it != teamA.end(); it++)
   {
    for(list<Alpha>::iterator itr = teamB.begin(); 
                                  itr != teamB.end();itr++)
    {
        it->addTarget(&(*itr));
    }
}
it = teamA.begin();
list<Alpha*>::iterator itr = it->getTargets().begin();
/// now trying to access it
while(itr != it->getTargets().end())
{
    (*itr)->display();
    itr++;
}

return 0;
}
```

And here is my output:

```
segmentation fault (core dumped) process returned 139 (0x8B)
```

Comment: I don't see the method `getTargets()` anywhere defined.

Comment: I didn't put it here for code brevity. It is actually there inside the Alpha.h class as setter and getter.

Comment: Since it is working with @sergej's code, I guess `getTargets()` returns a copy instead of a reference. This is why I asked for the method definition.

Comment: I suppose I was returning a copy. I changed the code from list<Alpha*> getTargets() const { return targets; } to list<Alpha*>& getTargets() { return targets;} . Now I realized what was my problem. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this what you expect?

```
it = teamA.begin();
list<Alpha*> targets = it->getTargets(); // local targets list copy! 
list<Alpha*>::iterator itr = targets.begin();

/// now trying to access it
while (itr != targets.end())
{
    (*itr)->display();
    itr++;
}
```

The problem in your code:

```
list<Alpha*>::iterator itr = it->getTargets().begin();
//                                      ^       ^
//                                      |       |
// returns a temporary list copy -------+       |
// returns an iterator to the temp. list copy --+
```

Now the temporary list is destroyed.

```
    (*itr)->display();
    itr++;
//   ^
//   |
//   +--- ERROR: iterator to a list that has been destroyed
```

Comment: It is working now, But I still do not understand why it was not working when I was trying to iterate through the local targets without copying into new list<Alpha*> ?

Answer (score 1):

As from the comments, the method `getTargets()` was defined as

```
list<Alpha*> getTargets() const
{
    return targets;
}
```

This returns a copy, which was used in

```
list<Alpha*>::iterator itr = it->getTargets().begin();
```

and

```
while(itr != it->getTargets().end()) {
```

as a temporary object, which will be destroyed immediately. This means `itr` is an iterator to a `list`, which no longer exists. When trying to access the object through the iterator, the program crashes.

When you copy the temporary list into a local variable, as @sergej did, or when you return a reference to the object's member, the list exists throughout the loop and the iterator points to a valid list.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough  explanation.